# How to get a list of students who haven't turned in their assignment/course (for a given assignment) work in Google Classroom?

Tags: java, android, google-classroom

I am trying to retrieve a set of students who haven't turned in their assignment for a given coursework. Does the Google Classroom API (Java) define any method or class for the same?

If it doesn't then, I had thought of an alternate approach (i.e. to retrieve all the students of the classroom and the ones who have submitted and it calculate who are missing from the list). But in that case I'm unable to get the users who have submitted their assignments.

What can I try to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When making a `courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions.get` request, you will receive a response with the following structure:

```
{
  "courseId": string,
  "courseWorkId": string,
  "id": string,
  "userId": string,
  "state": enum (SubmissionState),
  "late": boolean,
  ...
}
```

If you look closely, you will notice the presence of the `state` and the `late` field.

The former will have one of the following values:

- `SUBMISSION_STATE_UNSPECIFIED` -No state specified. This should never be returned.
- `NEW` - The student has never accessed this submission. Attachments are not returned and timestamps is not set.
- `CREATED` - Has been created.
- `TURNED_IN` - Has been turned in to the teacher.
- `RETURNED` - Has been returned to the student.
- `RECLAIMED_BY_STUDENT` - Student chose to "unsubmit" the assignment.

As for the latter, it will provide some insight on whether the assignment is submitted late or not.

Taking the above into account, you can determine which students have/haven't turned in their assignments and whether this has been done respecting the deadline.

#### Reference

- [Classroom API Resource courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions).